# Canvas not rendering images at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

I have an array of enemies sent from the server and I am recreating them because they were serialized. After, I'm trying to get them to render on the canvas, but that isn't working for some reason.

```
for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) { // recreate each enemy and render it
    var image = new Image();
    var currentFish = new Fish();
    for (var key in enemies[i]) { // copying properties to object that has the necessary methods
        if (enemies[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            currentFish[key] = enemies[i][key];
        }
    }
    image.src = currentFish.icon;
    image.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(image, currentFish.position.x, currentFish.position.y);
    };
    ctx.fillText('Drone', 250, 200);    
}
```

I think the issue is that `image.onload` is not called until after or in between frames so it isn't seen. I'm not sure how to work around this.

**Edit:**

I forgot to mention that I'm using requestAnimationFrame to handle rendering the canvas, so I don't know when the frame is going to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your outside `for` loop is overwriting the image variable with each loop (before the image can be loaded and drawn).

Try this alternative image loader which preloads all images into imgs[] and then calls start():

```
// image loader

var imageURLs = [];  // put the paths to your images here
var imagesOK = 0;
var imgs = [];
imageURLs.push("");
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function() { 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK >= imageURLs.length) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror = function() {alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start() {

    // imgs[] holds fully loaded images
    // imgs[] is in the same order as imageURLs[]

}
```

Comment: Why do you push an empty string at the beginning? Just to match imagesOK and imageURLs.length?

Comment: You should put your own urls where the empty string placeholder is:  imageURLs.push("yourImage.png");  :-)

Comment: Oh ok, I don't know the order of those (server-generated), so I'll just set up something for that and test it. Shouldn't `callback();` just be `ctx.drawImage();` also?

Comment: This won't work actually because I also have to know the position of the object that I'm drawing the image for, and since I'm using a callback, I can't store that information for every fish in a simple way. I meant shouldn't it just be the statement `ctx.drawImage();` instead of calling `callback();` that will just do that?

Comment: Sure, looping through your images and drawImage-ing them typically goes in the callback (start)--Along with any other initialization logic for your app.  Cheers!

Comment: You can attach additional properties to each individual image object:  img.startingX=100; img.starting=100;

Comment: if (imagesOK >= imageURLs.length) {
    ctx.drawImage(img, img.xPos, img.yPos);
   } is inside the onload, and i set up a breakpoint on that statement, the object doesn't show up on the canvas unless I run that statement in the console...

Comment: Unless I set a breakpoint, the object isn't drawn, any thoughts?